# C++11: why does std::condition_variable use std::unique_lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

I am a bit confused about the role of `std::unique_lock` when working with `std::condition_variable`. As far as I understood the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock), `std::unique_lock` is basically a bloated lock guard, with the possibility to swap the state between two locks.

I've so far used `pthread_cond_wait(pthread_cond_t *cond, pthread_mutex_t *mutex)` for this purpose (I guess that's what the STL uses on posix). It takes a mutex, not a lock.

What's the difference here? Is the fact that `std::condition_variable` deals with `std::unique_lock` an optimization? If so, how exactly is it faster?

Comment: Are you confused about why you need a lock/mutex with a condition variable, or about the difference between a lock and a mutex or about why a condition variable uses a unique lock and not a mutex?

Comment: "why a condition variable uses a unique lock and not a mutex" this.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

> so there is no technical reason?

I upvoted cmeerw's answer because I believe he gave a technical reason.  Let's walk through it.  Let's pretend that the committee had decided to have `condition_variable` wait on a `mutex`.  Here is code using that design:

```
void foo()
{
    mut.lock();
    // mut locked by this thread here
    while (not_ready)
        cv.wait(mut);
    // mut locked by this thread here
    mut.unlock();
}
```

This is exactly how one *shouldn't* use a `condition_variable`.  In the regions marked with:

```
// mut locked by this thread here
```

there is an exception safety problem, and it is a serious one.  If an exception is thrown in these areas (or by `cv.wait` itself), the locked state of the mutex is leaked unless a try/catch is also put in somewhere to catch the exception and unlock it.  But that's just more code you're asking the programmer to write.

Let's say that the programmer knows how to write exception safe code, and knows to use `unique_lock` to achieve it.  Now the code looks like this:

```
void foo()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lk(mut);
    // mut locked by this thread here
    while (not_ready)
        cv.wait(*lk.mutex());
    // mut locked by this thread here
}
```

This is much better, but it is still not a great situation.  The `condition_variable` interface is making the programmer go out of his way to get things to work.  There is a possible null pointer dereference if `lk` accidentally does not reference a mutex.  And there is no way for `condition_variable::wait` to check that this thread does own the lock on `mut`.

Oh, just remembered, there is also the danger that the programmer may choose the wrong `unique_lock` member function to expose the mutex.  `*lk.release()` would be disastrous here.

Now let's look at how the code is written with the actual `condition_variable` API that takes a `unique_lock<mutex>`:

```
void foo()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lk(mut);
    // mut locked by this thread here
    while (not_ready)
        cv.wait(lk);
    // mut locked by this thread here
}
```

1. This code is as simple as it can get.
2. It is exception safe.
3. The `wait` function can check `lk.owns_lock()` and throw an exception if it is `false`.

These are technical reasons that drove the API design of `condition_variable`.

Additionally, `condition_variable::wait` doesn't take a `lock_guard<mutex>` because `lock_guard<mutex>` is how you say:  I own the lock on this mutex until `lock_guard<mutex>` destructs.  But when you call `condition_variable::wait`, you implicitly release the lock on the mutex.  So that action is inconsistent with the `lock_guard` use case / statement.

We needed `unique_lock` anyway so that one could return locks from functions, put them into containers, and lock/unlock mutexes in non-scoped patterns in an exception safe way, so `unique_lock` was the natural choice for `condition_variable::wait`.

**Update**

bamboon suggested in the comments below that I contrast `condition_variable_any`, so here goes:

**Question:**  Why isn't `condition_variable::wait` templated so that I can pass any `Lockable` type to it?

**Answer:**

That is really cool functionality to have.  For example [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3427.html) demonstrates code that waits on a `shared_lock` (rwlock) in shared mode on a condition variable (something unheard of in the posix world, but very useful nonetheless).  However the functionality is more expensive.

So the committee introduced a new type with this functionality:

```
`condition_variable_any`
```

With this `condition_variable` *adaptor* one can wait on *any* lockable type.  If it has members `lock()` and `unlock()`, you are good to go.  A proper implementation of `condition_variable_any` requires a `condition_variable` data member and a `shared_ptr<mutex>` data member.

Because this new functionality is more expensive than your basic `condition_variable::wait`, and because `condition_variable` is such a low level tool, this very useful but more expensive functionality was put into a separate class so that you only pay for it if you use it.

Comment: Could you clarify "it".  Are you talking about `lock_guard`, or `condition_variable`, or perhaps `condition_variable::wait`?

Comment: Sorry, forget it. I totally forgot about `condition_variable_any`

Comment: <nod> Ah, template `condition_variable::wait`.  Yes, `condition_variable_any` is the way to go.  And the reason that functionality isn't folded into `condition_variable` is that it is more expensive.  And `condition_variable` is such a low level tool, it needed to be something that is as efficient as possible.  You only pay for the added functionality if you use `condition_variable_any`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the extra info. Maybe add that to your answer, as one could misuse `condition_variable_any` with a plain mutex.

Comment: Wow, I'm blown away by your answer. Thanks so much for this level of detail!

Comment: I am not yet completely convinced that "unique_lock was the natural choice for condition_variable::wait", since unique_lock has a little more overhead than lock_guard (it needs an additional boolean to know if the mutex is locked or not), but I may not want to pay this overhead if I just want to wait on a condition variable but not lock/unlock the mutex myself. Did the standard deem the overhead of requiring a unique_lock to use a condition variable negligible? Or is there some underlying technical reason why something as lightweight as lock_guard couldn't have worked?

Comment: The overhead of the test was considered acceptably small within the context of parking/unparking a thread.

Answer (score 37):

It's essentially an API design decision to make the API as safe as possible by default (with the additional overhead being seen as negligible). By requiring to pass a `unique_lock` instead of a raw `mutex` users of the API are directed towards writing correct code (in the presence of exceptions).

In recent years the focus of the C++ language has shifted towards making it safe by default (but still allowing users to shoot themselves into their feet if they want to and try hard enough).

Comment: so there is no technical reason?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `std::condition_variable` uses the `pthread_cond`, i.e. condition variable in Linux. `pthread_cond_wait_*` function needs a `mutex` as input variable. Only `unique_lock` has the member function to get a `mutex`. Everything else such as `lock_guard` or `scoped_lock` doesn't fit this requirements.