# why must I have a boost::mutex for boost::condition_variable?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, mutex

I have the following code:
where m_event is a boost::condition_variable

```
        boost::scoped_lock dummy;
        boost::unique_lock<boost::scoped_lock> lock(dummy); // TODO: see if dummy is correct
        m_event.wait(lock, [this] () {
            return !this ->m_enqueue.empty();
        });
```

I don't really need that dummy locker I just want the event to stop upon a certain boolean condition,
do I not understand something?

Why am I forced to use the dummy lock?

(P.S. code works great..)

EDIT:
In fact if I understood correctly, what I have in my class is a boost::mutex, let's call it m_mtx
and obvious inserters to the m_enqueue..
so I am changing my implementation accordingly to the lock to lock on m_lock and then the inserters would only do:

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock<boost::mutex> guard(m_lock);
```

make sense?

Comment: See [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099660/c11-why-does-stdcondition-variable-use-stdunique-lock)

Comment: @ichramm: That's a question! And [it's a subtly different one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099660/c11-why-does-stdcondition-variable-use-stdunique-lock#comment17804829_13099660), at that...

Answer (score 0):

`timed_wait` waits for a lock to be obtained, if it does so in time.

Without a lock, it can't do anything.

It seems to me you're abusing `timed_wait`.

Comment: timed_wait was recently added and is not releavnt, same question for wait

Comment: What do you mean it's "not relevant"? Your question is about it, is it not?

Comment: no, it's why I have to use the dummy mutex, if you remove the timeout all together, the question remains, I will edit

Comment: @Alon: Yeah, the timeout is not the important part of the question _or_ my answer. I don't really understand what you expect this function to do without a lock to work with.